# Как лучше поступить?

Tags: html, css, img

Как лучше поступить.
Мне на главный экран лэндинга нужна картинка, как лучше её задавать: 
Через background главного блока либо через img ?

И как сделать так, что бы на каждых break-points bootstrapa картинка отображалась как на главном (ничего не уходило за гринцы блока)

Comment: Картинка заднего фона?

Comment: Да, @Geri4. При чём я не хочу что бы она растягивалась

Comment: Да через background. У background очень много разных настроек, например background-size, где можно установить cover например, background-position... Так же если не ленится и прописывать media сможете добиться замечательных результатов

Comment: img как правило используется для того что бы разместить единицу информации, скажем так, в интернете, что то проиллюстрировать... Например статья и рядом иллюстрация или например коллекция фотографий или еще что то. Если нужен именно задний фон, используется background